# Calculating equilibrium constant for a general acid base reaction

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

I am trying to find the equilibrium value for different acid-base reactions. I have understood that when an acid and base are in an aqueous solution, many different reactions will occur. By combining these reactions, and multiplying their equilibrium constants, we can find the equilibrium value for an acid-base reaction.

**Example 1: $NH_3$ and $HCl$**

To illustrate my question I will take an example: if $NH_3$ and $HCl$ are in an aqueous solution, what reactions will occur? I believe the following reactions are those that will occur:

$HCl + H_2O ⇌ Cl^- + H_3O^+$, $K_1 = K_a(HCl) = 1.3 * 10^6$

$Cl^- + H_2O ⇌ HCl + OH^-$, $K_2 = K_b(Cl^-) = K_w/K_a(HCl)$

$NH_3 + H_2O ⇌ NH_4^+ + OH^-$, $K_3 = K_b(NH_3) = 1.8 * 10^{-5}$

$NH_4^+ + H_2O ⇌ NH_3 + H_3O^+$, $K_4 = K_a(NH_4^+) = K_w/K_b(NH_3)$

$2H_2O ⇌ H_3O^+ + OH^-$, $K_5 = K_w = 10^{-14}$ (the temperature is 25 degrees Celsius)

These are all the reactions that will occur in this solution, right? I noticed that adding all these will be of no use since the combined reaction will be the autoprotolysis of water. Instead, we only add reactions 1 and 3. That gives:

$HCl + NH_3 + 2H_2O ⇌ Cl^- + NH_4^+ + H_3O^+ + OH^-$, $K_6 = K_1 * K_3 = K_a(HCl) * K_b(NH_3)$

We can subtract the autoprotolysis of water from this reaction to get:

$HCl + NH_3 ⇌ Cl^- + NH_4^+$, $K_7 = K_6 / K_w = K_a(HCl) * K_b(NH_3) / K_w = 1.3 * 10^6 * 1.8 * 10^{-5} * 10^{14} = 2.34 * 10^{15}$

So the equilibrium constant for the reaction between $HCl$ and $NH_3$ is $2.34 * 10^{15}$; in other words, it essentially goes to completion. Is this correct?

**Example 2: $HCl$ and $NaOH**

Another example is the neutralization reaction between $HCl$ and $NaOH$. How should one deal with $NaOH$? Here is my attempt. The reactions that occur are:

$ HCl + H_2O ⇌ Cl^- + H_3O^+ $, $K_8 = 1.3 * 10^6$

$ NaOH → Na^+ + OH^- $, $K_9$, what should $K_9$ be?

In addition to these, $Cl^- + H_2O$ and the autoprotolysis of water will occur. Similarly to the first example, these reactions will be of no use to find the equilibrium constant for the neutralization reaction.

Adding reactions 8 and 9 gives:

$HCl + NaOH + H_2O ⇌ Cl^- + OH^- + Na^+ + H_3O^+$, $K_{10} = K_8 * K_9$

Can we here subtract the autoprotolysis of water as in the first example (since there is no "2" in front of "H_2O" on the left side of the reaction)? If we can do that then the reaction becomes:

$HCl + NaOH ⇌ Cl^- + Na^+$, $K_{11} = K_8 * K_9 / K_w$

I know that reaction 11 is unbalanced. $K_{11}$ is very large since $K_a(HCl)$ is very large and $K_9$ also is very large. So the reaction will essentially go to completion. However, it feels like something is wrong because reaction 11 is not balanced. What have I done wrong?

**Summary**

My goal is to understand the underlying theory of acid-base reactions and equilibrium. I have here presented in these two examples what I understand. What am I misunderstanding about how to calculate the equilibrium value for general acid-base reactions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: @Poutnik, thank you so much for your answer. I really appreciate it! Based on what you wrote, I should ignore that reaction between $NH_3$ and $H_2O$  (in my example nr 1) because it is negligible? Nevertheless, I want to gain a deep understanding of the topic, and thus want to consider all reactions involved and calculate the equilibrium value properly. I also understand that much bigger errors arise due to things outside of acid-base reactions, but that I am of course OK with that since it will not prevent me from understanding acid-base reactions properly.

Comment: I fully agree with that rule. Have I done a mistake in my question? If I have, although I don’t find it, I’m sorry. I will correct it immediately if you point it out. However, could you please help me with my original question. :)

Comment: Check the last 2 equations.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated reaction 10 (the next to the last one). As I wrote, the last equation is unbalanced, and that is why I feel that my approach is wrong (as I wrote in the original question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The rule No 0:** Learn to enumerate chemical reactions. The prerequisite is the knowledge of arithmetic of small natural numbers. Total charges and total atom counts must be equal on both reaction sites. No atom is created nor destroyed during any chemical reaction.

**The rule No 1:** Simplify everything where simplification brings negligible error, otherwise you often end with too complicated math. Considering strong acids as HCl or strong bases as NaOH as completely dissociated brings very negligible error ( with much bigger ignored error due activity versus concentration).

**The rule No 2:** After the calculation, verify if conditions for the simplification are met. If they are not, you have to reject simplification.

E.g., we want to derive an equation of pH of diluted solution of weak acid. The dissociation constant for a weak acid is:

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{[\ce{H+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]}$$

If we assume $\ce{H+}$ from water autodissociation is negligible, compared to  the acid dissociation ($[\ce{H+}] \gg [\ce{OH-}]$), we can simplify it using  $[\ce{H+}] \approx [\ce{A-}]$ to:

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{[\ce{H+}]^2}{[\ce{HA}]}$$

If we then also assume near all acid is not dissociated ($c \approx [\ce{HA}]$), we can simplify it to:

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{[\ce{H+}]^2}{c}$$

leading to

$$c \gg [\ce{H+}] \gg [\ce{OH-}] \implies \mathrm{pH} = \frac 12(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} - \log{c})$$

**The rule No 3:** Any respective conjugate pair acid/base (like $\ce{NH4+}$/$\ce{NH3}$) is in water solutions in first place in equilibrium with $\ce{H2O}$/$\ce{H+(aq)}$/$\ce{OH-(aq)}$ respectively. Any equilibrium with other acid/base system is indirect, dependent and redundant.

**The rule No 4:** Any acid-base reaction in water is generally reaction of some acid passing a proton to some base, the former becoming a base and vice versa.

$$\ce{\mathrm{acid}_1 + \mathrm{base}_2 <=>  \mathrm{base}_1 + \mathrm{acid}_2}$$

---

> How to calculate the equilibrium constant for the reaction between $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ (in my example nr 1) and between $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$ (in my example nr 2). Could you please show me how you would do that using your method (if my method is wrong?).

- Example No 1: The equilibrium constant is experimentally determined for NH3(aq) + H2O(l) <=> NH4+(aq) + OH-(aq).
  You have already listed it in your question as $K_\mathrm{b} = \pu{1.8E-5}$.
- Example No 2: It is equilibrium $\ce{H2O <=> H+(aq) + OH-(aq)}$ with $K_\mathrm{w} = \pu{e-14}$ at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$, as HCl and NaOH are in water (with negligible error) fully dissociated. $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions are often called spectator/bystander ions that do not take part in the reaction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I agree with what you say. However, my original question is how to calculate the equilibrium constant for the reaction between $H_2O$ and $NH_3$ (in my example nr 1) and between $HCl$ and $NaOH$ (in my example nr 2). Could you please show me how you would do that using your method (if my method is wrong?)

Comment: See the answer update.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that! Sorry, I meant the reaction between $HCl$ and $NH_3$ and not between $H_20$ and $NH_3$ (my example no 1 in the question). Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is trivial,  Ka=Kw / Kb // K=[NH4+]/([NH3][H+]) = 1/Ka = Kb/Kw. // Learn to ignore bystanders.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Do you mean that the $H^+$ and $Cl^-$ ions are bystanders so we should ignore them from the reaction? If that were the case, the equilibrium constant for the reaction between $HCl + NH_3$ would be the same as that between $NH_3 + H_2O$ which is $1.8 * 10^{-5}$. However, that is not true, since the reaction between $HCl + NH_3$ essentially goes to completion. Sorry for misunderstanding you!

Comment: No, I do not say that. think longer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. And I have been thinking about this for a while now. What are the bystander ions in the following reaction you are talking about: $HCl + NH_3 ⇌ Cl^- + NH_4^+$. I cannot find any.

Comment: Cl- is bystander.. As it is safe to assume there is no HCl in H2O.

Comment: It seems you need rather systematic topic study than asking on Q/A site, which just fills the gaps. / 
Look at 1/ education focused site: [chem.libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org)   2/ [Chemistry cheat sheets on Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/chemcon.html) 3/  [Learning resources recommended by Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)